# How to find out "the right" IP address?

Tags: java, ip-address

I have a problem with InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(). It works correctly on most machines, but it fails on one where there are more IP addresses available (in this case "the wrong" address belongs to VMware network adapter). I need the address to put it into a message (which then is used on the server as an address where a response should be sent).

I know that I may use NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() to get all network interfaces but how I may programatically find the right one which is later visible for the server? In my particular case both clients and the server are located inside the same corporate network.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking for is possible -- in fact, I think it is plain impossible, since a VM does not know, and cannot know (unless a security bug lurks) such a thing.

Comment: I am not good in network interfaces but is it really impossible for a computer to find which from its IP addresses is used to get into the machine from the other machines?

Comment: "I need the address to put it into a message (which then is used on the server as an address where a response should be sent)." Why? The server already knows what client socket address and port were used to connect to it.

Comment: Unfortunately somebody who designed the server haven't thought of using the IP from the socket connection. As far as I know the server just puts the incomming txt message into a queue. When another piece of code handles the message it takes the information where to sent the reply from the text message. The incomming IP address is not used on the server :(

Answer (score 1):

If all machines are in the same network and this network has its IP range, you may check if IP is in this range. Usually vmware network adapters have IPs in 192.168.0.x subnet - if your corporate range is different, then it should be enough.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not in the same subnet: for example server address starts with 172. and the problematic client with 193.

Comment: Do you know machine's name? If yes, you can use tools like `nslookup`, `nmap`. If you know your DNS server's IP, you can use `arp-scan` to list connected IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following class to help with IP

```
public enum IpAddressHelper
{

    X_FORWARDED_FOR("X-Forwarded-For"),
    PROXY_CLIENT_IP("Proxy-Client-IP"),
    WL_PROXY_CLIENT_IP("WL-Proxy-Client-IP"),
    HTTP_CLIENT_IP("HTTP_CLIENT_IP"),
    HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IpAddressHelper.class);
    private static final String REMOTE_ADDR = "REMOTE_ADDR";
    private String key;

    /**
     * @param key
     */
    IpAddressHelper(String key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

    /**
     * @return the key
     */
    public String getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    public static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request)
    {

        String ip = null;
        for (IpAddressHelper header : IpAddressHelper.values())
        {
            if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
            {
                ip = request.getHeader(header.getKey());
                LOGGER.info("tried:" + header);
            }
        }

        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
        {
            ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
        }

        return ip;
    }

    public static String getClientIpAddr(Map<String, String> requestHeaders)
    {
        String ip = null;
        for (IpAddressHelper header : IpAddressHelper.values())
        {
            if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
            {
                ip = requestHeaders.get(header.getKey());
                LOGGER.info("tried:" + header);
            }
        }

        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip))
        {
            ip = requestHeaders.get(REMOTE_ADDR);
        }

        return ip;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using socket communication not HTTP so unfortunately it doesn't help much :(

Comment: @GUZ okay, well so i will leave this for people who might be using HTTP